# Creating a Stacked Sankey Plot (or other stuff) to Analyze Survey Questionnaire Composition in R

Tags: r, visualization, sankey-diagram

Before I start, please know that I am a complete beginner in R. I am familiar with the Stata language. I also generated this fake dataset from ChatGPT to give you a better idea of my problem.

```
  Variable_name Source_dataset Survey_Year Section Order_Section
1          Var1      Household       1986       A             1
2          Var2     Individual       1992       B             2
3          Var3      Household       1998       C             3
4          Var4     Individual       2004       A             1
5          Var5      Household       2010       B             2
```

What I want to do is to produce some visual, neat descriptive statistics about how the composition of a questionnaire varies throughout time. I want a chart where one can see:

- The wave of the survey given by variable Survey_Year (1986, 1992, etc.)
- For each wave of the survey, the order of the sections of the questionnaire (Section A, Section B, etc)
- For each section of each survey, the number of variables contained (given by a count of Variable_name).

I also wish to indicate the observation unit given by Source_dataset for each section, but I don't really know how.

What I was thinking was basically doing a sankey plot with Survey_Year on the X-axis and the number of observation in the Y-axis. One stacked bar for each year, with one sub-bar a particular color for each section. In between bars, flows to see how sections vary in ranking (imagine section A going from first to second btw 1986 and 1992) and in number of variables. But I don't know how to give an additional layer of information for Source_Dataset.

Any suggestion matter!

I have no knowledge of R and therefore did not try anything yet.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. It sounds like you don't even know exactly what output you want right now. If you want advice on data visualization, then maybe ask at [stats.se] instead where that's on-topic.